# How to initialise in C++11 in one line a vector of n equal elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization, stdvector

I know in C++11 I can construct a vector with a syntax like:

```
vector <int> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

but is it possible without looping in a similar way to initialise the vector for a number of equal elements ?

e.g.

```
int n= 5;
vector <string> a = (n, {"bbb"});
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes,

```
vector<string> a(n, "bbb");
```

This works in C++03 too.

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there. There's a constructor to specify the size and (optionally) a value to initialise the elements with:

```
vector<string> a(n, "bbb");
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked everywhere in s.o. and then the answer was just in the c++ ref:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

It should be as simply as:

```
int n= 5;
vector<string> a (n,"bbb");
```

Comment: FWIW, that is not "the C++ ref". And `const` please!